# Does the heat created by gravitational energy cause Infinite energy?

Tags: gravity

As everyone knows there is this thing called geothermal energy. Many people in Iceland and such countries get their energy from geothermal plants. My question is since some of the heat in the earth is caused by gravity and that heat is used for energy, isn't the geothermal energy created by the gravity within the earth infinite energy?

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly! I am not sure I am following how you make the jump to "infinite energy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say that gravity is the source of the heat inside a planet, what we mean is this: when the planet first forms by the gravitational attraction of the gases and dust in a cloud, the gas and dust that are at the center of the cloud are being compressed together by all the gas and dust in the outer layers of the cloud. As the cloud gathers itself together and becomes denser, the stuff in the center will get squeezed harder and harder which causes its temperature to rise. Once the planet has formed itself into a more-or-less solid sphere, the center is really hot because of that pressure, and the fact that the heat has a hard time getting out of there.

But it will, by convection and conduction out of the core,and than by radiation into space- at which point the work performed by gravity in compressing and heating the center will be dissipated away. So the gravitational heating is not *infinite*.

Comment: Crystal clear thank you Niels nielsen!

Comment: Gravity still compresses the Earth and produces energy for the Earth's core and mantle.

Comment: Gravity produces no energy for the core and mantle. It applies compressive stress and converts gravitational potential energy into heat.